# Accessing HTML script variable from google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-picker

I'm trying to put together a picker in google sheets.
Once a file has been uploaded to google drive, I want the url to be posted in the current cell in the spreadsheet.

This is my pickerCallback located in an html file:

```
var message;

function pickerCallback(data) {
    var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
    if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        var id = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=' + doc[google.picker.Document.ID];

        google.script.run.accessSpreadsheet(); 

    } message = id;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
}
```

This returns the url in the picker dialog box.

My accessSpreadsheet function looks like this and is located in a google script file:

```
function accessSpreadsheet() {
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
     var currentCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
     currentCell.setValue(message);
     return spreadsheet;
}
```

The function runs but it cannot define message. Is there a way to access the variable defined in the function in the html file from the google scripts function? Or is there another better way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109538/trying-to-read-cell-1-1-in-spreadsheet-using-google-script-api

Check this out. May be helpful

Comment: Thank you for the response, however this doesn't really relate to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution:

Pass the string `id` from  client side to server.

#### Snippets:

```
google.script.run.accessSpreadsheet(id);
```

---

```
function accessSpreadsheet(id) {

 currentCell.setValue(id);
```

#### Reference:

[Client-Server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Is there any place I can learn more about this?

Comment: @PhilipB Added a reference.