# How to compare value of a cell <-> string

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking to compare the value of a cell to a string. (In google scripts)

```
function MyMovingTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MYIDHERE"); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SHEETNAMEHERE");

  if(sheet.getRange('B2').getValue()=="TRUE") { 
    //more code here
  }
}

//The value in B2 is the following:
//this will either display "TRUE" or "FALSE"
=ISREF(INDIRECT("Copy of Empty"&"!C1"))
```

The error I get back is the following: 
ReferenceError: Function function getValue() {/* */} can not be used as the left-hand side of assignment or as an operand of ++ or -- operator. at MyMovingTrigger(Code:8)

Comment: This seems to have been asked before and answered. Please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109538/trying-to-read-cell-1-1-in-spreadsheet-using-google-script-api

Comment: Which line is line 8?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if(sheet.getRange('B2').getValue() == true) {
```

i.e get rid of the quotes around TRUE and put in lowercase.